# how to use browser scroll for x-overflow of internal div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement a dynamic page with a tree like structure that exceeds the width very easily. I want to scroll the tree through the browser's horizontal scrollbar itself such that a separate scroll does not appear for the div. The CSS properties are:

```
body{
overflow-x:auto;
background-color: #ffffff;}

#campaign {
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
white-space: nowrap;}
```

Here is the screenshot for my current output.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpRlt.png)

The bottom horizontal scroll disappears when you scroll vertically up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set overflow to `visible` in the container div and that will cause the contents to go out of 100% width bounds and add the scrollbar on the body.

Here’s a simplified example: https://jsbin.com/bejimit/edit?html,css,output

And its CSS:

```
body {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

#campaign {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.content-item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the campaign div does not extend in this case which leads to ui problems for other javascript tools used in the campaign div. I need to extend the campaign div as it grows bigger and somehow use only browser scroll to scroll through the campaign div.

Comment: All you need to do for that is add `display: inline-block` to `#campaign` as well, I updated the example and code.

Comment: That would work in case of static elements but like i said my page is dynamic with scripts generating and placing elements according to other element. This gives the same wrong output. This campaign is also both vertically and horizontally scalable .

Comment: @YashChamadia without you providing more detail about type of content and styles applied it’s hard to help you

Comment: There are nodes in campaigns that are interconnected via branches forming a tree structure. There is a button that opens a popover on click on every node. The positions of the popovers are calculated via offset of the node clicked. If overflow is equal to visible for campaign div, the positions calculated via .offset() function are relative to the page that is in view of the browser ignoring the part that has already been scrolled. When attaching the popover, it shows up acc. to the absolute position. This problem does not occur if overflow is auto as the offset value is absolute in that case.